# Need help to figure out a solution to this UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode, utf-8, unicode-string

When I use this code (adapted from  [Stephen Holiday code](http://stephenholiday.com/articles/2011/gender-prediction-with-python/) - thanks, Stephen for your code!):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python    
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
USSSALoader.py
"""
import os
import re
#import urllib2
from zipfile import ZipFile
import csv
import pickle

def getNameList():
    namesDict=extractNamesDict()
    maleNames=list()
    femaleNames=list()
    for name in namesDict:
        counts=namesDict[name]
        tuple=(name,counts[0],counts[1])
        if counts[0]>counts[1]:
            maleNames.append(tuple)
        elif counts[1]>counts[0]:
            femaleNames.append(tuple)
    names=(maleNames,femaleNames)
    return names

def extractNamesDict():
    zf=ZipFile('names.zip', 'r')
    filenames=zf.namelist()

    names=dict()
    genderMap={'M':0,'F':1}

    for filename in filenames:
        file=zf.open(filename,'r')
        rows=csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')

        for row in rows:
            name=row[0].upper()
           # name=row[0].upper().encode('utf-8')
            gender=genderMap[row[1]]
            count=int(row[2])

            if not names.has_key(name):
                names[name]=[0,0]
            names[name][gender]=names[name][gender]+count

        file.close()
        print '\tImported %s'%filename
    return names

if __name__ == "__main__":
    getNameList()
```

I got this error:

```
  iterator = raw_query.Run(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\datastore.py", line 1622, in Run
    itr = Iterator(self.GetBatcher(config=config))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\datastore.py", line 1601, in GetBatcher
    return self.GetQuery().run(_GetConnection(), query_options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\datastore.py", line 1490, in GetQuery
    filter_predicate=self.GetFilterPredicate(),
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\datastore.py", line 1534, in GetFilterPredicate
    property_filters.append(datastore_query.make_filter(name, op, values))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\datastore\datastore_query.py", line 107, in make_filter
    properties = datastore_types.ToPropertyPb(name, values)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\datastore_types.py", line 1745, in ToPropertyPb
    pbvalue = pack_prop(name, v, pb.mutable_value())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\datastore_types.py", line 1556, in PackString
    pbvalue.set_stringvalue(unicode(value).encode('utf-8'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This happens when I have names with non-ASCII caracters (like "Chávez" or "Barañao"). I tried to fix this problem doing this:

```
     for row in rows:
           # name=row[0].upper()
            name=row[0].upper().encode('utf-8')
            gender=genderMap[row[1]]
            count=int(row[2])
```

But, then, I got this other error:

```
 File "C:\Users\CG\Desktop\Google Drive\Sci&Tech\projects\naivebayes\USSSALoader.py", line 17, in getNameList
    namesDict=extractNamesDict()
  File "C:\Users\CG\Desktop\Google Drive\Sci&Tech\projects\naivebayes\USSSALoader.py", line 43, in extractNamesDict
    name=row[0].upper().encode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I also tried this:

```
def extractNamesDict():
    zf=ZipFile('names.zip', 'r', encode='utf-8')
    filenames=zf.namelist()
```

But `ZipFile` doesn't have such argument.

So, how to fix that avoiding this `UnicodeDecodeError` for non-ASCII names?

I'm using this code with GAE.

Comment: Could [the python doc](http://docs.python.org/faq/programming#what-does-unicodeerror-ascii-decoding-encoding-error-ordinal-not-in-range-128-mean) help you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your first traceback is AppEngine-related. Are you building a loader that will populate the datastore? If so, seeing the code that comprises the models and does the `put`'ing would be helpful. I will probably be corrected by someone, but in order for that piece to work I believe you actually need to `decode` instead of `encode` (i.e. when you read the sheet prior to the `put`, convert the string to unicode by using `decode('utf-8')` or `decode('latin1')`, depending on  your situation).

As far as your local code, I won't pretend to know the deep internals of Unicode handling, but I've generally used `decode()` and `encode()` to handle these types of situations. I believe the correct encoding to use depends on the underlying text (meaning you'd need to know if it were encoded `utf-8` or `latin-1`, etc.). Here is a quick test with your example:

```
>>> s = 'Chávez'
>>> type(s)
<type 'str'>
>>> u = s.decode('latin1')
>>> type(u)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> e = u.encode('latin1')
>>> print e
Chávez
```

In this case, I needed to use `latin1` to decode the encoded string (I was using the terminal), but in your situation using `utf-8` may very well work.

Comment: Tanks, @RocketDonkey. If I try decode('utf-8'), I got this error: `C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py 16  
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 2: unexpected end of data` If I try decode('latin1'), there is no error, but the names are returned from this script and saved in my database (in other script) this way: u'C\xe9SAR' instead of u'César' and u'ANT\xc3\x94NIO' instead of u'Antônio'. Any additional tip?

Comment: @Pythonista'sApprentice Have you checked what the information looks like when you output it? For instance, if you were to read data from the datastore and print it to a page (or however your app handles it), does it appear correctly? I believe that you are just seeing how the datastore is storing the data internally (as unicode), and you should be able to output the data and have it appear as `César` and `Antônio` (you may need to perform the `encode()` step on the returned data before printing).

Comment: Thanks, it's almost perfect, with some mistakes: `Antônio` turns into `Antânio`. I'll check this.

Comment: Good to hear! Hopefully you can get it sorted out; if not, happy to help troubleshoot.

Comment: your help was worth!! In almost all cases is working well! But now I'm trying to remove the accents, but getting this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014810/how-to-fix-this-unicodedecodeerror-that-appears-when-i-try-to-remove-accents-in Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, this line in the library:

```
pbvalue.set_stringvalue(unicode(value).encode('utf-8'))
```

should be:

```
pbvalue.set_stringvalue(value.decode(filename_encoding).encode('utf-8'))
```

And the value `filename_encoding` passed in from your code if not stored in the zip archive somehow (and at least in the early versions of the format, I doubt it's stored).  It's yet another occurrence of the classic error of assuming that bytes and "characters" are the same thing.

If you're feeling froggy, dive into the code and fix it, and maybe even contribute a patch.  Otherwise, you'll have to write heroic code that checks for U+0080 and above in filenames and performs special handling.

Answer (score 0):

In python 2.7 ( and linux Mint 17.1) , you must use:
hashtags=['transito','tránsito','ñandú','pingüino','fhürer']
    for h in hashtags:
        u=h.decode('utf-8')
        print(u.encode('utf-8'))

> > transito
> >     tránsito
> >     ñandú
> >     pingüino
> >     fhürer