# How to fix this UnicodeDecodeError that appears when I try to remove accents in Python strings?

Tags: python, unicode, non-ascii-characters

I'm trying to use this function:

```
import unicodedata

def remove_accents(input_str):
    nkfd_form = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', unicode(input_str))
    return u"".join([c for c in nkfd_form if not unicodedata.combining(c)])
```

in the code below (which unzips and reads files with non-ASCII strings). But I'm getting this error, (from this library file `C:\Python27\Lib\encodings\utf_8.py`):

```
Message File Name   Line    Position    
Traceback               
    <module>    C:\Users\CG\Desktop\Google Drive\Sci&Tech\projects\naivebayes\USSSALoader.py    64      
    getNameList C:\Users\CG\Desktop\Google Drive\Sci&Tech\projects\naivebayes\USSSALoader.py    26      
    remove_accents  C:\Users\CG\Desktop\Google Drive\Sci&Tech\projects\naivebayes\USSSALoader.py    17      
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Why am I getting this error? How to avoid it and make `remove_accents` work?

Thanks for any help!

Here's the entire code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import re
from zipfile import ZipFile
import csv

##def strip_accents(s):
##   return ''.join((c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'))

import unicodedata

def remove_accents(input_str):
    nkfd_form = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', unicode(input_str))
    return u"".join([c for c in nkfd_form if not unicodedata.combining(c)])

def getNameList():
    namesDict=extractNamesDict()
    maleNames=list()
    femaleNames=list()
    for name in namesDict:
        print name
#        name = strip_accents(name)
        name = remove_accents(name)
        counts=namesDict[name]
        tuple=(name,counts[0],counts[1])
        if counts[0]>counts[1]:
            maleNames.append(tuple)
        elif counts[1]>counts[0]:
            femaleNames.append(tuple)
    names=(maleNames,femaleNames)
 #   print maleNames
    return names

def extractNamesDict():
    zf=ZipFile('names.zip', 'r')
    filenames=zf.namelist()

    names=dict()
    genderMap={'M':0,'F':1}

    for filename in filenames:
        file=zf.open(filename,'r')
        rows=csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')

        for row in rows:
            #name=row[0].upper().decode('latin1')
            name=row[0].upper()
            gender=genderMap[row[1]]
            count=int(row[2])

            if not names.has_key(name):
                names[name]=[0,0]
            names[name][gender]=names[name][gender]+count

        file.close()
  #      print '\tImported %s'%filename
   # print names
    return names

if __name__ == "__main__":
    getNameList()
```

Comment: Searching for UnicodeDecodeError on SO yields dozens and dozens of questions, and they all have more or less the same answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best practice is to decode to Unicode when the data comes into your program:

```
for row in rows:
    name=row[0].upper().decode('utf8') # or whatever...you DO need to know the encoding.
```

Then `remove_accents` can just be:

```
def remove_accents(input_str):
    nkfd_form = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', input_str)
    return u''.join(c for c in nkfd_form if not unicodedata.combining(c))
```

Encode data when leaving your program such as writing to a file, database, terminal, etc.

Why remove accents in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to robustly convert unicode characters to ascii in a string, you should use the awesome [unidecode](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/) module:

```
>>> import unidecode
>>> unidecode.unidecode(u'Björk')
'Bjork'
>>> unidecode.unidecode(u'András Sütő')
'Andras Suto'
>>> unidecode.unidecode(u'Ελλάς')
'Ellas'
```

Answer (score 2):

You get it because you are decoding from a bytestring without specifying a codec:

```
unicode(input_str)
```

Add a codec there (here I assume your data is encoded in utf-8, `0xe1` would be the first of a 3-byte character):

```
unicode(input_str, 'utf8')
```

Comment: I think in Python3 this would have worked without specifying a codec.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: why do you think that? Python 3 has a default codec for encoding from a bytestring too, which can fail still.

Comment: Isn't it UTF8 by default on Python3 @Martijn?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: just for the source code, not for encoding and decoding. See the [Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/py3k/howto/unicode.html#unicode-howto). Besides, what if the input is latin-1? Then you still have the wrong encoding if there was a default other than ASCII..

Comment: Cheers @Martijn. +1 - I assumed it was default to utf8 for decoding also; since in the source it was the default.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: even better: *unless* you specify a codec, `str()` in python 3 will not decode a bytestring. It'll return the `repr()` of the bytstring instead when you omit a codec. Try `str(bytstring)` vs. `str(bytestring, 'utf8')`. No more implicit decoding with unexpected defaults!

Comment: Hi, @MartijnPieters, I followed your suggestion:`nkfd_form = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', unicode(input_str, 'utf8'))` but now I got this error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 3: unexpected end of data` . Any tip?

Comment: That happens when you're decoding an object that's _already_ unicode.

Comment: I edited my last comment, did you read it? If you read, how, then, could I remove the accents from the unicode string?

Comment: @Pythonista'sApprentice: You can't just slap "utf8" in as an encoding and expect it to work.  You need to know what encoding your bytes are using, and specify that encoding.  You seem not to have utf8 data.  Perhaps it is iso8859-1?  We're just guessing.  You have to know where your bytes came from, and what encoding they are using.  See [Pragmatic Unicode, or, How Do I Stop The Pain](http://bit.ly/unipain) for more details.